# Reference for the Grothendieck's standard conjectures on algebraic cycle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-cycles

Is there any source explaining or dealing with Grothendieck's Standard Conjectures on algebraic cycles in detail?
For example, in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conjectures_on_algebraic_cycles),

1. What does "Lefschetz operator ($\Lambda$) is induced by an algebraic cycle. (Conjecture B)" mean?
2. What does "the projectors are algebraic (Conjecture C); i.e., induced by a cycle $\pi^{i} \subset X \times X$ with rational coefficients" mean?

And so on...

I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: I am against closing this question. In particular, I think what the question is asking for is plenty clear and not lacking for any relevant details.

Answer (score 2):

I think both of your questions (and more) are well-answered by [Grothendieck's original paper](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eleila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/StandardConjs.pdf).

Comment: As an aside, this is the second source which shows up when one searches "Grothendieck algebraic cycles" or "Grothendieck standard conjectures" on Google. It also appears as a source in the Wikipedia article you yourself link. In the future, I would gently suggest searching a little more before posting a question as above. (Of course, it's possible that you've tried to read Grothendieck's paper, and find it unsatisfactory. But if that's so, then you should mention it (and your reasons) in your question, especially since I find his paper beautiful, clear, and succinct.)

Comment: O.K. I'll try to search associated data. Thank you ~